# Minimize SQL Server stress on queries from a read only schema

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to make sure the stress to the server is minimal while running queries from a read only schema (a user can select data and create temp tables and variables, but can't execute SPs, write and other more advanced stuff). What db hints/other tricks could I use in this situation?

Currently I am:

1. Using the `WITH (NOLOCK)` hint for every table
2. Setting the `DEADLOCK_PRIORITY` for the whole batch to -10 (although I am not sure it's really needed, since I am using `NOLOCK`)

My goals is to take as little server resources as possible and allow other more important things to be processed by the server freely. The queries that I am going to send to the server are local (can't be saved as SPs) and there will be many of them coming from various users every 5 minutes. They are generally simple `SELECTs` and are cheap in isolation. Are there any other ways to make them even less expensive?

EDIT:
I am not the owner of the server I am connecting to, so I can only use the SQL query I am passing to the server to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two measures you have taken will have little impact. They are mostly used out of superstitiousness. They *can* have an impact in rare cases. Practically, `READ UNCOMMITTED` (which is 100% identical to `NOLOCK`) enables allocation order scans on B-trees. That is only important for tables that are not in-memory anyway.

If you want to minimize locking and blocking, snapshot isolation can be a simple and very effective solution.

In order to truly minimize the impact of a certain workload you need to use Resource Governor. Everything else are partial solutions/workarounds.

Consider limiting CPU usage, memory, IO and parallelism.

Comment: Thanks, now I see it is not apparent from my question, but the problem is, I am not the owner of the server I am going to connect the users to. So the only things I can do need to be embedded in the SQL query I send to the server.

Comment: In that case you have done all you could. Delete all the NOLOCK stuff and set TRAN ISOLATION LEVEL RUC. Consider LOCK_TIMEOUT = 0 or some other low value. This can lead to sporadic failures, of course. RUC can also lead to sporadic query failures.

Comment: Can you move it to the answer, so that I can accept it? Also, since you`re saying NOLOCK is the same as RUC, why are you suggesting to exchange them?

Comment: Because it is tedious to apply NOLOCK everywhere. Comments are part of the answer, so I'll leave them here.